# Cannot mount encrypted LUKS drive with "x-gvfs-show" option

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab, luks

I've used Linux Mint 16 Petra's Disks utility to format my external drive as an encrypted LUKS ext4 partition.

The problem is that I can't mount it if I use the option "Show in user interface", that adds a "x-gvfs-show" parameter to my fstab file.

If I remove this parameter I can mount it correctly but I don't see the drive in Nemo.

The output of "dmesg | tail" just after I try to mount the drive is:

```
[  724.841456] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 2094.754682] EXT4-fs (dm-3): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
[ 2114.994445] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 6286.799200] EXT4-fs (dm-3): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
```

A workaround that I've found is to disable that option, mount the drive, then add it back and the drive will be showed into Nemo's sidebar, but I'd prefer to avoid this boring steps every time I boot up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you found this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1012081

The util-linux package in Ubuntu 13.10 is still the version 2.20 (2012). It is a very critical package and must be updated with a lot of caution, and in sync with upstream, although probably in this case there have been a bit of overzealous safety...

On the other hand, it can be seen as a bug of gvfs for using features not present in the stable version of the package, here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1011257

So I basically think there is an impasse here.

I hope (but I do not think) that the update will land in 14.04.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this problem. So there's no solution except a, possibly dangerous, manual update of util-linux? It seems pretty absurd to me that such a basic feature isn't working correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I will add a bit more info, but the bug was assigned on  2012-06-19  but is still here. Embarassing, yes.